Git seems to always try to get content in an anonymous way first
When cloning a repository or fetching the content of a private repository, I noticed that Git seems to always try to get the content in an anonymous way. When this attempt fails, it will then use the credentials provided.
There is an  advantage of this behaviour with public repositories.
However, when dealing with private repositories that require credentials, we end up with unnecessary calls on the server and a lot of 403 error messages on the server.
Is there a way to tune git so that it will always provide the credentials ?

You're going to have to provide some details. Show the evidence you're looking at, don't just characterize it and generally talk about your conclusions, what specifically led you to ask this?

Basically, I looked at the logs on my github enterprise side. I can see on the /var/log/github/gitauth.log that everytime I clone a repository (which is not public), I get a line with a gh.gitauth.member="anonymous" gh.gitauth.status="unauthorized_access_to_private_repository" status=403 for accessing this repo, followed by another line with a status="200".  When I clone a public repository, I do not get this 403 error code on the server. That is why it seems git client tries to access anonymously first. Then if it fails, it requests the creds.

My first question here would be does it matter? Do you see delays that can be attributed to this 403 connection, or is it just resolved and retried in a flash? I would only try to optimize this if you see performance issues due to it.

My second comment is if you use the ssh URL for your remote (git@github.com:user/project) instead of https, then it will always authenticate.

It does matter in the sense that we are dealing with a server hosting more than 100,000 repositories, with many jenkins and other CI making a lot of requests. As all our repos are private and require authent, changing this behaviour would decrease the number of unnecessary requests on our server.  As for the usage of SSH instead of HTTPS, this has been restricted for security reasons...
